# Issue with reading a file through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to read a file called config.txt on a button click

```
Host:www.fff.com
Username:root123
Password:root123
```

This is my submit part of  html file

```
<input name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:left;" onClick="contact_mailsend();" id="Submit" value="SUBMIT" type="submit" />
```

on click will trigger a JS function contact_mailsend():

```
function  contact_mailsend(){
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        var tmpDoc, re=/^(.+)$/gm, arr=[], oP,arrSplit=[],arrSpl=[];
        if(xmlHttp.readyState===4){
            if(xmlHttp.status===200){
                tmpDoc=xmlHttp.responseText; arrSpl = tmpDoc.split(",");
                var arrGlobalHost = arrSpl[0].split(':');
                var arrGlobalUser= arrSpl[1].split(':');
                var arrGlobalPass= arrSpl[2].split(':');
                strGlobalHost = arrGlobalHost[1];
                strGlobalUser = arrGlobalUser[1];
                strGlobalPass = arrGlobalPass[1];
                alert(strGlobalHost);
                xmlHttp=null;
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", fileName, true); //Use POST to prevent use of cached file
        xmlHttp.send(); 
    }; 
};
}
```

What's happening is that alert inside is happening not at the first time.

Submit click on first click never alert. If submit is clicked for second time, it will alert.

Please help me.

Comment: Is that submit button inside a form? If so the form is submitted!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vw6NBVuTvKUo3SFXVBdP)

Try moving the `xmlHttp.send()` out of `onreadystatechange` event handler. When you click, the form will be sent.  When the response changes, your callback function will execute and alert.

```
function  contact_mailsend(){
    xmlHttp.open("POST", fileName, true); //Use POST to prevent use of cached file
    xmlHttp.send(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        var tmpDoc, re=/^(.+)$/gm, arr=[], oP,arrSplit=[],arrSpl=[];
        if(xmlHttp.readyState===4){
            if(xmlHttp.status===200){
                tmpDoc=xmlHttp.responseText; arrSpl = tmpDoc.split(",");
                var arrGlobalHost = arrSpl[0].split(':');
                var arrGlobalUser= arrSpl[1].split(':');
                var arrGlobalPass= arrSpl[2].split(':');
                strGlobalHost = arrGlobalHost[1];
                strGlobalUser = arrGlobalUser[1];
                strGlobalPass = arrGlobalPass[1];
                alert(strGlobalHost);
                xmlHttp=null;
            }
        } 
    }; 
};
```

Comment: without seeing your code, it will be hard to debug.  Are you preventing default submit?  When you click on the button, does the page refresh?

Comment: <input name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:left;" onClick="contact_mailsend();" id="Submit" value="SUBMIT" type="submit" />

Comment: I've added a demo Plunker in the answer.  I am using GET method in the demo because I am just grabbing a simple text file.